# Create an Array of vectors in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, stdvector, distance-matrix

I want to create a distance matrix of a big dataset, and only want to store the 'close' enough elements. The code reads like this

```
vector<double> * D; 
D = (vector<double> *) malloc(dim *sizeof(vector<double>) ) ;

for(i=0;i<dim;i++){
    for(j=i+1;j<dim;j++){
        dx = s[j][0] - s[i][0];
        dy = s[j][1] - s[i][1];
        d =   sqrt( dx*dx + dy*dy );
        if(d  < MAX_DISTANCE){
            D[i].push_back(d);
            D[j].push_back(d);
            }
        }
```

which gives me segmentation fault. I guess I have not defined the array of vector correctly. How do I get around this  ?

Comment: Don't use `malloc` in c++.

Comment: Why make an array of vectors when you can just make a vector of vectors?

Comment: Use a single `std::vector<double>` and have its size be `width*height`.

Comment: @Galik because in a vectors of vectors I would have to cycle on the full array for every element and cant start from j=i+1. Am I wrong ?

Comment: Its really no different from an array of vectors. In fact a vector is actually a dynamic array wrapped in a class. Try your example with this: `std::vector<std::vector<double> > D(dim);`.

Comment: @DuccioPiovani Using `std::vector<std::vector<double>> D(dim);` solves your problem, given what you posted.  Why not run it and see that it works correctly?

Comment: @Galik thanks it works.

Comment: @PaulMckenzie Thank you !!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C++ you should *never* allocate object (or arrays of objects) using `malloc`. While `malloc` is good at allocating memory, that's all it does. What it *doesn't* do is calling constructors which means all your `vector` objects are *uninitialized*. Using them will lead to *undefined behavior*.

If you want to allocate an array dynamically you must use `new[]`. Or, better yet, use `std::vector` (yes, you can have a vector of vectors, `std::vector<std::vector<double>>` is fine).

---

Using the right [vector constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) you can initialize a vector of a specific size:

```
// Create the outer vector containing `dim` elements
std::vector<std::vector<double>> D(dim);
```

After the above you can use the existing loops like before.

Comment: Thanks Joachim. The reason I want to use the and array is for the cycle and make j start at i instead of 0. With a vector I can't do it (ora at least I wouldn't know how.)

Comment: @DuccioPiovani  You should read on how to [resize](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/resize) the vector to the size you want, even if you knew nothing about the constructor.

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg this was very useful. Just made me save a lot of time. I thank you very much for that.